# What particle should I use with "motomeru"?

Tags: grammar, particles

In the sentence `Honne o motomeru` is `o/wo` (を) the correct particle to use?

Comment: voted to close: you're question is unintelligible (at least to me). Do you want to conjugate or to know the right particle? Second point, "o" and "wo" are just the same thing (just quit using romaji) written differently, but the same anyways. Could you at least tell us the phrase your attempting to translate (are you sure about honne (real intentions), is it not hon (book)).

Comment: @変幻出没 I just want to know the right particle yes.

Comment: @変幻出没 and yes it is definetly honne; i.e: seek real intentions

Comment: The "を" particle can be confusing. It's usually romanized as "wo", but the pronunciation is virtually always "o". There is no "o" particle. It's just "wo".

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect what I think you are trying to ask. 'Conjugation' is about changing verbs (motomeru, motomenai, motomete, etc). It's quite a big change from the original though so say if you don't like it and I'll reverse it.

Comment: @Ash Thank you very much the question indeed better reflects what I'm trying to find

Comment: The answer to the question is definitively yes, but I feel it's a bit short for a true answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the sentence `Honne o motomeru` is `o/wo` (を) the correct particle to use?

Yes.

> What particle should I use with “motomeru”?

The reason why "を" is the correct particle for your example clause, is because "求める" is a transitive verb, and "本音" is the object.

---

In addition to transitive verbs, there are intransitive verbs. Usually you can either find an intransitive version, or a conjugation that essentially is intransitive, for every transitive verb.

From [guidetojapanese.org](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/in-transitive):

> In Japanese, sometimes there are two types of the same verb often referred to as transitive and intransitive verbs. The difference between the two is that one verb is an action done by an active agent while the other is something that occurs without a direct agent.